# Loading and saving a data file in android

Tags: java, android, file, load, save

I am doing a simple application that loads and saves files in java. I am trying to port it over to Android and am having trouble getting it to see the file.

The file path I am currently using is

```
private static final String SAVE_FILE_PATH = "data/save";
```

Here is the function that loads the data from the file:

```
public void loadData() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(SAVE_FILE_PATH);

    Scanner scanner;

    if (file.exists()) {

        scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                allPlayers.add(new Player(scanner.nextLine()));
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No file found");
    }

        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: your file path should be in below format.."/mnt/sdcard/yourfilename"

Comment: Don't count on "/mnt/sdcard" being the correct path.  Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `getExternalStorageDirectory()` gets you the path to the SD card, consider using `Activity.getExternalFilesDir()` which will return (and create if necessary) a directory that's nominally private to your application.  It also has the advantage that it will be auto-deleted for you if the application is uninstalled.  This is new in API 8, so you might not want to use it if you're supporting older devices.

Otherwise, you'll have to follow ρяσѕρєя K's advice.  Don't forget to create the storage directory you want to use.  My code typically looks like this:

```
/**
 * Utility: Return the storage directory.  Create it if necessary.
 */
public static File dataDir()
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if( sdcard == null || !sdcard.isDirectory() ) {
        // TODO: warning popup
        Log.w(TAG, "Storage card not found " + sdcard);
        return null;
    }
    File datadir = new File(sdcard, "MyApplication");
    if( !confirmDir(datadir) ) {
        // TODO: warning popup
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to create " + datadir);
        return null;
    }
    return datadir;
}


/**
 * Create dir if necessary, return true on success
 */
public static final boolean confirmDir(File dir) {
    if( dir.isDirectory() ) return true;
    if( dir.exists() ) return false;
    return dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Now use this to specify your save file:

```
File file = new File(dataDir(), "save");

Scanner scanner;

if (file.exists()) {
  // etc.
}
```